# Moving a GCP VM to a new Organisation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am forced to move my VM to a new organisation because of domain name registry issues. I can't just change my G Suite primary domain as I am a G Suite reseller, they don't allow the primary domain name change. I have created a new G Suite account (Google is transferring the reseller privileges), but in the mean time I'll need to move the VM to the new organisation and project I created.

The VM is running Plesk and is active with multiple accounts live on it. Therefore I'm hoping to get this done with minimal downtime and error.

Can I just move the VM or do I have to move the project?
Has anyone done this before and have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

To move VM instances between projects in GCP [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501141/how-to-move-an-instance-between-two-projects-in-google-cloud-platform) and the answer is it isn't possible.

You can move a project from one organization to another [in three steps](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration).

Check [this post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-move-a-vm-instance-between-projects-on-google-cloud-platform-39d1690c73a) for a guide to achieve a similar result related with the first question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I'll be giving this a shot this weekend. I like the post from medium.com, it has much more detailed instructions than the Google website.